# Using results of JOIN statement to join on the results of another JOIN statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have the following 2 Join Statements:

```
--Get Total Hrs
DECLARE @BeginDate datetime, @EndDate datetime
set @BeginDate = '01-01-2013'
set @EndDate  = '12-31-2013'
BEGIN
SELECT F.Type, E.Product, SUM(F.Hours * E.Amount) AS 'Total Hours' 
FROM Hours H
INNER JOIN Equipment E
ON F.SN = E.SN
WHERE (F.Date BETWEEN @BeginDate AND @EndDate)
GROUP BY F.Type, E.Product
ORDER BY  Product ASC
END

--Get Number of Unscheduled Removals
DECLARE @BeginDate1 datetime, @EndDate1 datetime
set @BeginDate1 = '01-01-2013'
set @EndDate1  = '12-31-2013'
BEGIN
SELECT LEFT(dbo.fn_GetPartName(R.PartID),CHARINDEX('-',dbo.fn_GetPartName(R.PartID), 1) - 1) AS 'Part No', 
Count(s.status) AS NumberUnscheduledRemovals
FROM Repair R
INNER JOIN Conversion C
ON  R.Performed = C.Performed 
AND R.Confirmed = C.Confirmed
INNER JOIN Status S
ON C.StatusID = S.StatusID
WHERE (R.Received BETWEEN @BeginDate1 AND @EndDate1)
AND (S.Status = 'UNSCHEDULED')
GROUP BY LEFT(dbo.fn_GetPartName(R.PartID),CHARINDEX('-',dbo.fn_GetPartName(R.PartID), 1) - 1)
ORDER BY LEFT(dbo.fn_GetPartName(R.PartID),CHARINDEX('-',dbo.fn_GetPartName(R.PartID), 1) - 1) ASC
END
```

Both queries have results including `part numbers` (these have the same values).  I want to `INNER JOIN` the results from both queries on the resulting `part numbers`.   have been trying for a while but cant seem to get the syntax right to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a temp table using CREATE TABLE #TempPartNum1 & #TempPartNum2.

Grab all the relevant data from the first two queries and put them in the temp tables, then join the temp tables.

Comment: Excellent!!!  That was a quick and easy solution.  Instead of using CREATE... I simply used INSERT INTO #myTempTbl on the first query and then DROPPED the #myTempTable at the end of the 2nd query and just made a storedProcedure for the future.  Thanks for the solution

Comment: I spent a few years coding stored procedures for Sybase (SQL's distant cousin).  #Temp tables were the most common approach to solving and decomposing complex procedural tasks. Other RDBMS flavors (Oracle, MySQL, etc.) would have merited a different approach.  It goes to show that you really need to be aware of your working environment (i.e., SQL Server, Transact SQL) before you choose a solution or approach!

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a CTE ("Common Table Expression"):

```
;WITH QueryOne AS (
... put your first query here
), QueryTwo AS (
... put your second query here
) SELECT blah blah blah
  FROM QueryOne INNER JOIN QueryTwo ON foo = bar
```

CTEs are very handy for things like this.